# Using Include() with anonymous types in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, eager-loading

I am trying to eager load some properties using Include method as following:

```
var dbData = dbContext.Locators.Include(x => x.PhysicalObjects.Select(p => p.Parent)).Include(x => x.PhysicalObjects.Select(p =>p.Type.AllowedSubTypes))
                .Where(x => x.id==1)).Select(x => new
                {
                    newContainer = x.PhysicalObjects.Where(p => p.Id== newContainerId).FirstOrDefault(),
                    phyiscalObject = x.PhysicalObjects.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault()
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

But it returns Parent and Type properties as null(I checked database they are not null).

So how can I eager load those properties?

P.S

I am using Entity Framework V6.1.3

Comment: You should also double check your mapping, if you have any. It may happen when you missconfigure your relations.

Comment: I have tried out this query:
dbContext.PhysicalObjects.Include(x => x.Parent).Include(x => x.Type.AllowedSubTypes).Where(x => x.Id == the_wanted_id).FirstOrDefault();

It returns them

Comment: `Include`s are ignored in projection queries.

Comment: @IvanStoev So could you please provide me a solution to get my work done?

Comment: you can use .Where().Take(1).ToList().Select().FirstOrDefault(). this will query the top result before projection and therefore fill the navigation properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on DevilSuichiro's comment above the query will be like this:

```
 var dbData = dbContext.Locators.Include(x => x.PhysicalObjects.Select(p => p.Parent)).Include(x => x.PhysicalObjects.Select(p =>p.Type.AllowedSubTypes))
                .Where(x => x.Id==1)).Take(2).ToList().Select(x => new
                {
                    newContainer = x.PhysicalObjects.Where(p => p.Id== newContainerId).FirstOrDefault(),
                    phyiscalObject = x.PhysicalObjects.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault()
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

It worked for me, but I will still be waiting for better answer if any.